# Android activity lifecycle has bugs when locking unlocking the device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lifecycle

I'm quite confused to not find information about this on the internet.

I have a simple app, when the activity is paused and resumed works fine in the following scenarios:
when it is by tapping the home button, recents, back button and any other event

BUT when the power button is used to lock the screen and unlock the UI is freezed.

So I lock the device and I unlock it and the app does not behave correctly Ui not working, etc.

And this strange behaviour is fixed by pausing and resuming the activity by for example tapping home and then the app icon, or recents.

Some apps I have installed don't have this behavior so it must be fixable.

How can I fix it?

Comment: what does your activity do?